# PostgreSQL: Delete all but most recent date

Tags: postgresql, delete-row

I have a table defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE contracts (
  ContractID TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  ContractName TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  ContractEndDate TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
  ContractPOC TEXT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

In this table, a ContractID may have more than one record, for each ContractID I want to delete all records but the one with the latest ContractEndDate. I know how to do this in MySQL using:

```
DELETE contracts
  FROM contracts
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      ContractID,
      ContractName,
      max(ContractEndDate) as lastDate,
      ContractPOC
    FROM contracts
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0) Duplicate on Duplicate.ContractID = contracts.ContractID
    WHERE contracts.ContractEndDate < Duplicate.lastDate;
```

But I need help to get this working in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use this

```
delete 
from 
    contracts c
using (SELECT
          ContractID,
          max(ContractEndDate) as lastDate
        FROM 
            contracts
        GROUP BY 
            ContractID) d
where
    d.ContractID = c.ContractID
    and c.ContractEndDate < d.lastDate;
```

Comment: This works perfectly! :) I did discover that in my data there were many duplicates on ContractID, ContractEndDate, so I just put in another DELETE immediately before this one to remove those duplicates before feeding them into your code.